# How to change OpenStack Ceilometer MySQL reporting password

Tags: sqlalchemy, openstack

Have asked this question on Ask OpenStack, but few views and no responses.

I'm trying to use the SqlAlchemy (basically MySQL) driver and have found that the password the driver attempts to use is set to ''. This is the password for the driver used by the reporting API, not collection.

I assume this is a default set somewhere, but I can't find it. Have looked through the config and setup files, and tried to find where the CFG object is created, and even traced through with the debugger.

The reason I know it's a password problem is because when the MySQL password is set to something other than '', the driver encounters a MySQL authentication error. When I set the database password (in MySQL for root user) to empty, the driver can authenticate.

My localrc has MYSQL_PASSWORD set to 'password', but the driver can't authenticate when MySQL uses that password.

Anyone know where to set this password for the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, the file `ceilometer/storage/__init__.py` contains a struct called `STORAGE_OPTS`.  Adding a similar entry to the array will cause it to use the DB of your choice:

```
cfg.StrOpt('database_connection',
           default='mysql://root:password@localhost:3306',
           help='Database connection string',
           ),
```